# How to Avoid Recalculation of Data in R

Tags: r

When working in R I typically create a number of intermediate data frames that get saved off during execution of the code.  This allows me to avoid recalculating the intermediate data frames if I need to restart the script or it crashes.  My code usually ends up with a lot of these ugly if/else checks to see if the intermediate data frame already exist.

```
data <- NULL
pathToData <- "work/data.rds"
if(file.exists(pathToData)) {
   # load the previously calculated data
   data <- readRDS(pathToData)

} else { 
   # calculate the data
   data <- ...  
   saveRDS(data, pathToData)
}
```

Is there a better/simpler way to do this?  Ideally this could be done in a manner that is transparent in the code.

Comment: What means exactly "get saved off" (send to a file? or...)? What about simply saving the workspace?

Comment: You could clean that up by defining a function that takes a file name and a function to compute the data, and returns the data from the file if it exists, otherwise saves the result of the function to the file and returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drew Steen's answer was real close. I paired his function definition with his suggested use of eval().  This is exactly what I was looking for.

```
cache <- function(cacheName, expr, cacheDir="work", clearCache=F) {
    result <- NULL

    # create the cache directory, if necessary
    dir.create(path=cacheDir, showWarnings=FALSE)
    cacheFile <- sprintf("%s/%s.rds", cacheDir, cacheName)

    # has the result already been cached?
    if(file.exists(cacheFile) && clearCache==F) {
        result <- readRDS(cacheFile)

    # eval the expression and cache its result
    } else {
        result <- eval(expr)
        saveRDS(result, cacheFile)
    }

    return(result)
}
```

This allows me to either cache single function calls...

```
result <- cache("foo", foo())
```

Or more complex expressions/code blocks...

```
results <- cache("foo", {
   f <- foo()
   r <- f + 2
   return(r)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to wrap the ugly code in a function, and wrap your intermediate steps in other functions. This has the advantage of making your testing easier, and using functions over scripts is considered best practice for reproducible data analysis.

```
calcData <- function(...) {
  #calculate the data
}

lazyCalc <- function(fn, ...) {
  if(file.exists(fn)) {
    data <- readRDS(fn)
  } else {
     calcData(...)
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do something like this, but I would need to get the name of the function that is passed in to lazyCalc.  In your implementation the name of the cache file will always be "fn" no matter which function is passed.  That won't work.  Does anyone know how I can get the name of a function passed as an argument?

Comment: This post will probably help you - you'll use `eval()` http://blog.earlh.com/index.php/2009/06/eval-in-r-running-code-from-a-string/

Comment: Yep!  eval() is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the knitr package with caching.

You could create a full knitr template file with your script and other things included and set the chunks that you do not want to be rerun to be cached, then they will only be run a second time if the code in that chunk changes.

You could also use the `spin` function from knitr on the script file, then knitr will look at specially formatted comments to set knitr options (everything else will be essentially treated as a regular script file).  I have not tried setting cache info with `spin` but it may work for you.